# Given a classmethod reference, how to get a reference to the class in which it is defined?

Tags: python-3.x, class-method

I have a bound classmethod refference at some point in the code. I want to get the class itself from it. How can I do it?

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        ...
...

method_reference = A.class_method

...

reference_to_A = method_reference.bound_class # how to get it?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__self__`:

```
>>> class A:
...     @classmethod
...     def class_method(cls):
...             pass
...
>>> method_reference = A.class_method
>>> method_reference.__self__
<class '__main__.A'>
```